# How to remove layers of detail from an osm file?

Tags: openstreetmap, layers

I want to remove some layers from the osm map of an area. It has all the details like POI, offline routing and all. But I just want the map data. How can I remove this extra layer from the map?

Comment: Please, clarify how do you utilise OSM?

Comment: Actually I download the osm files. Now when I load the files it has all the details with map like POI and all. I don't want all these stuff. I just need simple map and remove all the extra feature how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are no layers as such. You have points (=nodes), lines (=ways) and relations between those. They can have attributes (=tags), which represent [map features](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features). If you want to have a map of just the features you're interested in, you can use tools like [TileMill](http://mapbox.com/tilemill/) or [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/) to generate such maps. It all depends on your concrete needs - do you need a Web map, a bitmap, a vector map...

Comment: I need a vector map. Actually I downloaded the vector map in osm format. I just want plain roads not POI and all. When I loaded the osm file it shows everything how to remove this

Comment: If by "OSM format" you mean OSM XML, then this is not really a vector map - it's raw geo data encoded in XML form. I think you should start by reading the basics: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners_Guide_1.5

Answer (score 0):

There is a utility call Osmfilter (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter):

> osmfilter is used to filter OpenStreetMap data files for specific tags. You can define different kinds of filters to get OSM objects (i.e. nodes, ways, relations), including their dependent objects, e.g. nodes of ways, ways of relations, relations of other relations.

It supports .osm and .o5m files.