# How can I see the layers in an .OSM file?

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have an osm file. I am trying to convert it to geojson with ogr2ogr. I get an error that ogr2ogr can't handle multiple layers. How can I tell what layers are in the file and remove them? I see from [How to remove layers of detail from an osm file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24330/how-to-remove-layers-of-detail-from-an-osm-file) that OSM files might not even have layers. So what is the meaning of this error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OGR OSM driver categorize features into 5 layers:

> - points : "node" features that have significant tags attached.
> - lines : "way" features that are recognized as non-area.
> - multilinestrings : "relation" features that form a multilinestring(type =    'multilinestring' or type = 'route').
> - multipolygons : "relation" features that form a multipolygon (type = 'multipolygon' or type ='boundary'), and "way" features that are recognized as area.
> - other_relations : "relation" features that do not belong to the above    2 layers.

You have to specify the layer that you are interested in. For instance if your are interested in `points` you would use the following command:

```
ogr2ogr your-new-file your-osm-file.osm points
```

For more information have a look at the [OGR OSM drive specifications](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_osm.html).

Comment: Just to avoid any misunderstandings: Currently the [OSM data schema](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Data_Primitives) itself doesn't know a layer concept.